Retrieving data using two columns with two where conditions
products table
Get products where amount=0 and versionno=highest for a particular productno:
SELECT ProductNo, MAX(VersionNo) AS VersionNo
FROM Products
WHERE Amount = 0
GROUP BY ProductNo
HAVING MAX(VersionNo) = (SELECT MAX(VersionNo) 
                         FROM Products 
                         WHERE ProductNo = Products.ProductNo)

I am expecting



productno
versionno
amount




10
3
0


30
2
0




Do you expect us to copy the data (from that picture), to see what the result it from your query, and why that does not match the expected output ? (Please read: Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? )

Using the data from the fiddle in the answer from @Atif, i do see that the current result is empty?  (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/WTgXw2lX )

Proper use of aliases is solving this problem:
SELECT p1.ProductNo, MAX(p1.VersionNo) as VersionNo
FROM Products p1
WHERE p1.Amount = 0
GROUP BY ProductNo 
HAVING MAX(p1.VersionNo) = (SELECT MAX(p2.VersionNo) 
                            FROM Products p2 
                            WHERE p2.ProductNo = p1.ProductNo)

see: DBFIDDLE

Technically, you can remove the HAVING thing, and it will work just as well, tbh, not sure what the OP is looking for

@siggemannen: Is that really true? I do not think so because WHERE p1.Amount = 0 is not in the subquery

Hmm, that's true. In some cases, he will get no rows at all? Then i understand even less what OP wants :D

You can make use of Analaytical query i.e. over clause with max to get the required result.
SQL fiddle
-- Create the test table
CREATE TABLE test (
    ProductNo INTEGER NOT NULL,
    VersionNo INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Amount NUMERIC
   
);

-- Insert data into the test table
INSERT INTO test (ProductNo, VersionNo, Amount) VALUES 
(10, 1, 100),
(10, 2, 120),
(10, 3, 0),
(20, 1, 45),
(20, 2, 0),
(20, 3, 55),
(20, 4, 78),
(30, 1, 120),
(30, 2, 0);

with CTE1 AS
(
select productno, versionno,  max(versionno) over(partition by productno) max_versionno, amount
from test)
select productno, versionno, amount from cte1 where amount = 0 and versionno = max_versionno;

